# Interpreting coefficient from linear model when the dependent variable has been first log transformed then z-transformed

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients, logarithm, z-score

I'm trying to predict the amount of personal votes a political candidate gets based on how attractive they look. I have data from a general election and a local election. The dependent variable is highly right skewed, so I have log-transformed it. In order to make the personal vote data comparable across elections, I have aslo z-transformed the log(personal votes). My question is: What is the substantive interpretation of the coefficient for the independent variable, when the dependent variable has been first log-transformed then z-transformed?

```
#Example data
set.seed(123)
attractiveness <- rnorm(1000, mean = 5, sd = 1)
age <- rnorm(1000, mean = 35, sd = 10)
gender <- sample(c(0, 1), 1000, replace = TRUE)

# personal votes - general election
personal_votes_ge <- exp(rnorm(500, mean = 100, sd = 1))
personal_votes_ge_transformed <- (log(personal_votes_ge) - mean(log(personal_votes_ge)))/sd(log(personal_votes_ge)) 

# personal votes - local election
personal_votes_le <- exp(rnorm(500, mean = 50, sd = 1))
personal_votes_le_transformed <- (log(personal_votes_le) - mean(log(personal_votes_le)))/sd(log(personal_votes_le)) 

personal_votes <- c(personal_votes_ge, personal_votes_le) 
personal_votes_transformed <- c(personal_votes_ge_transformed, personal_votes_le_transformed)

election <- rep(1:2, each = 500)

#The model
model <- lm(personal_votes_transformed ~ attractiveness + gender + age, data = data)
```

Comment: If you used a different z-transform in each election (which seems to be what you are saying), then your regression coefficients are not directly comparable: in effect, they all use different units of measurement and different origins.  Consider backing up a little and thinking about those transformations: maybe there's a different way to model your data that will be more interpretable.  After all, having a skewed response variable is not much of a reason to transform it.